# How to implement this way of indicating current tab in navigation?

Tags: javascript, html, css

A new trend in design is to, for navigation menus, show a thin line under the links and make the line thick under the link for the current page you're on. It looks like this:

[image]

How would one go about implementing this? Just CSS or JavaScript as well?

Answer (score 1):

this is only a border being changed I guess.

You can always do something like this:

```
.menubutton{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.menubutton:hover,
.menubutton.active{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
```

And add some Javascript to activate/deactivate them...

```
$('.menubutton').click(function (){
  $('.menubutton').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```